# would return 0 using C++ in a class outside of main close the application?

Tags: c++, class, return-value

I'm currently working on implementing patch files in some code, and apparently one of the patch files uses return 0 in a class outside of the main. I know return 0 would close the application if it was in the main function, however I'm not sure about how it would function in a class outside of the main function. Basically the code could be summed up like this in pseudocode:

```
boost::uint64_t
namespace::class(etc. etc.)
{

   if (method.isValid)
   {
      //do stuff
   }
return 0;
}
```

Normally when I think of return 0 in C++, I think of exiting the application by calling it in main, however in this case, I'm not sure if this would exit the application, or just the class's functionality/the class it self. Could someone please explain what the return 0 would actually be doing in this situation?

Thanks,
Flyboy

Comment: If you had a function that returned the value a^2+b, would you expect that that would stop the program from running?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

Think of what would happen if this was the case:

```
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

// somewhere:
int zero = add(2, -2); // would this exit the program?
```

It isn't the zero that is important in the return from `main`, it's the `return`.  You can return any value from `main` and doing so will cause the program to exit (after all global variables are cleaned up, streams are closed, and other cleanup tasks are completed).

Comment: Thanks, this makes things a lot more clear. The return and not the value in main causing exit is something that is good to know as well, I was not aware that it was just the return, but I thought it was the whole return 0; that caused it.

Answer (score 3):

No, returning 0 (or anything else) from a function won't exit the application.  Returning from main -- *regardless* of the value returned -- exits from a (single-threaded) application. But other functions come and go all the time.

Answer (score 3):

`return 0` is only relative to the scope of the current function so it will not close the application if it is outside of main.

Answer (score 3):

Returning from `main` exits the application (regardless of the value being returned -- though the standard only defines meanings for `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`). Returning from some other function just returns the designated value (if any) to the caller. The control flow doesn't change just because the value being returned happens to be zero.